# What is the CNF for At Most One?

Tags: logic

Learning CNF for the very first time and am confused by the notation.

From "[A New SAT Encoding of the At-Most-One Constraint](http://www.it.uu.se/research/group/astra/ModRef10/papers/Jingchao%20Chen.%20A%20New%20SAT%20Encoding%20of%20the%20At-Most-One%20Constraint%20-%20ModRef%202010.pdf)" page 6

```
Let X = {x1, x2, ...,xn}

The standard SAT encoding of the At Most One constraint is the following:

AMO(X) = {!xi V !xj | xi,xj in X, i<j}

This AMO encoding requires n(n-1)/2 clauses
```

For example, what would be the CNF for X = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5} and what would be the 5(4)/2 = 10 clauses?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the given recipe:
$$ (\neg x_1\lor \neg x_2)\land (\neg x_1\lor \neg x_3)\land  (\neg x_1\lor \neg x_4)\land  (\neg x_1\lor \neg x_5)\land (\neg x_2\lor \neg x_3)\land  (\neg x_2\lor \neg x_4)\land  (\neg x_2\lor \neg x_5)\land  (\neg x_3\lor \neg x_4)\land  (\neg x_3\lor \neg x_5)\land  (\neg x_4\lor \neg x_5)$$

Comment: thank you, that really helped. However, now that I see it, I am not understanding how this means the same as at most one...but that may be another question.